# Ubuntu Server 13 hangs on boot, help?

Tags: boot, server, permissions, startup, raid

All that appears on the screen is the blinking cursor, and it never seems to go away.

I am pretty sure this may be a permissions problem.

The reason I suspect this, is before the problem occured I had change the owner of the /home directory. (I was debugging an FTP issue at the time) I forgot to reset the owner back to root before restarting though. And ever since, it has not successfully booted.

the command I used:
`chown -R ftpuser:users /home`

For some stupid reason I decided it was a good idea to have this set at startup so it is in `/etc/rc.local` as well.

Normally I would just change the perms back in RecoveryMode, but it seems I can't get there (esc & left shift aren't working).

Any ideas what this could be, or how I could fix it?

**P.S.**
For more fun, the system was setup in RAID1, so mounting it while in a live CD is extra tricky.

Answer (score 0):

I would change your rc.local chown and set permissions with a live CD or USB key, didn't [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15933/how-to-access-md-raid-via-live-cd) help you ?